# I am getting an unexpected token error when using an else statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Before the unexpected token error i got a '}' is expected error was wondering why that is was able to fix it but did not want to run into that issue again. thank you.

[image]

Comment: add your code here

Comment: This is a simple syntax error not a question

Comment: You're not running this code inside of a method.  Seems like a typo at worst, a duplicate at best...

Answer (score 2):

If there is single statement inside if case, {} not always required. If you try
with

```
if(x==y){
   System.out.println("");
 } else {
   System.out.println("");
 }
```

Or

```
if(x==y)
    System.out.println("");
else 
    System.out.println("");
```

is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single statements in your `if`/`else` blocks,  you either may choose to have this statement in open braces or you have to opt out on both the cases.

**VALID**:

```
if( x == y ) {
    System.out.println("The reminder is " + result);
} else {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

**OR**

```
if( x == y )
    System.out.println("The reminder is " + result);
else
    System.out.println("Hello");
```

**INVALID**:

```
if( x == y )
    System.out.println("The reminder is " + result);
} else {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Hope this answers your question well!

Answer (score 0):

You have not started the `{` of the **if** condition and You should use `x === y` as it will check value as well as the type.

Note: Do not add an image if you have the problem in your code. Add the code use `{}` in the editor of the stack overflow to format your code. This helps other people to answer your question easily.